# Mastercard Insomnia Plugin - File read location

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, insomnia, mastercard

TL;DR: Getting p12 not file found error when using Mastercard Insomnia plugin. "No P12 file found at location: defaultsandboxsigningkey.p12"

I'm trying to test the [Mastercard Insomnia Plugin](https://github.com/Mastercard/insomnia-plugin-mastercard/tree/main), which tries to read a p12 file based on an environment variable. Internally, the plugin uses the nodejs' readFileSync, function as seen [here](https://github.com/Mastercard/insomnia-plugin-mastercard/blob/7f0c43ccce5b2596df1551bd8b5139d507d84544/src/auth/oauth.js#L10C72-L10C72).

From what I understand, the readFileSync function(as used there) takes the received path as a relative path from where the script is executed. So I'm wondering where does this script get executed from? I've tried setting an absolute path using "~/" but it does not work.

I've also tried putting it in multiple file locations inside the plugin folder(which is located at ~/Library/Application Support/Insomnia/plugins/insomnia-plugin-mastercard) and putting a simple "./name_of_p12_file.p12" on the environment variable, but I've had no success.

Note: When I say "environment variable" I mean an Insomnia env variable, not a system/os env var.

Comment: `as seen here.` or, you could add the relevant code to the question itself